# connect android to mysql trough java

Tags: java, android, mysql, servlets

I want to connect to MySQL database (online) from android. I want to use java for the connector. Would be servlet enough or is there a better way?

Comment: a webservice should be enought, if I'm understanding clearly your question.

Comment: Basic concept is to call a php script from your app (php script will access your database), get the response back in the form of html/json/etc, then parse and use it in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a PHP script. You can follow [this tutorial](http://m-zeeshanarif.blogspot.fr/2013/05/android-connecting-to-server-mysql.html) I used it and it's really simple

Comment: It is recommended to provide the important parts of the link in your answer here. That way, your answer stays valid even if the link goes dead.